# Django Models Relations to User Model

Tags: python, django, models

I'm new to the forum and I've got a problem.

in Django im trying to create a UserProfile class by referencing it via a OnetoOneField to an User Object. When i try to migrate, I get:

"You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to author without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py"

I understand, that there are some fields in the User model (for example "id") that are not allowed to be null.

When I try to set a default it will makemigrations, but migrate fails with a syntax error.

My Question is how do I allow Null, or set a default that works, without writing a custom User class, and is that even possible ?

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Here is my Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as User_django

class User(User_django):
    pass

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)

class BaseElement(models.Model):

    author=models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True)
    upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def vote_up(self):
        self.upvotes.value = self.upvotes.value + 1

    def vote_down(self):
        self.downvotes.value = self.downvotes.value + 1

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Post(BaseElement):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    said_by = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    said_at = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all()

    def get_comments_anzahl(self):
        return self.comment_set.all().count()


class Comment(BaseElement):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    commented_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_query_name="comment", null=True)
```

EDIT:

This happens if I try to set a default and try to migrate:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to author without a  
default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate 
existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can  
do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> 1
 Migrations for 'post':
 0003_auto_20160505_1237.py:
  - Change Meta options on author
  - Change managers on author
  - Remove field user_ptr from author
  - Add field id to author
  - Add field user to author

 Operations to perform:
 Apply all migrations: contenttypes, admin, sessions, post, auth
 Running migrations:
   Rendering model states... DONE
   Applying post.0003_auto_20160505_1237...Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
   return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
   sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django  /core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
   executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake,  fake_initial=fake_initial)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
   state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
   operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 121, in database_forwards
   schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 247, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_fields=[field])
    File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 197, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
     return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "/home/jaidmin/.conda/envs/cyf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
   django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

EDIT: 
It seems like I solved it by creating a new project and step by step copying the models and migrating. Still wondering what was going on there, because I flushed the database and deleted the migration files multiple times and it was still throwing errors.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You should show how you tried to set the default, and the error you got.

Comment: It may also help to delete any problematic migrations and regenerate them from scratch on a fresh database.

Comment: Indeed, the brute-force way to solve such problems is to 1) drop database; 2) manually delete all the migration files in migrations folder (just don't delete `__init__.py`); 3) create empty database; 4) `python mange.py makemigrations`; `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import django's built-in `User` model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and delete this line:

```
class User(User_django):
    pass
```

from your code as it is completely unnecessary.

**UPDATE:** Also it looks like your problem has nothing to do with the `User` model. I think somehow you added an id field to your `Author` model and deleted it (maybe after an unsuccessful migration). If this is the case, then you could edit your `0003_auto_20160505_1237.py`. To do that open it and remove the lines which look something like this:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='author',
    name='id',
    field=models.someFieldType(options)),
),
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just had that class to try to set default values for the User Fields that were non nullable, but the Fields clashed. After deleting and just keeping Author (for Userprofile purposes), I still get the same issue. Django asks for a default value for the user.id, but what is and acceptable value there ? If i set a Sting like "default" it will makemigrations but migrate fails with "django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

Comment: Looks like your problem has nothing to do with the `User` model. I think somehow you added an id field to your `Author` model and deleted it (maybe after an unsuccessful migration), isn't that the case?

Comment: Thank, must have been that. I ended up creating a new project and copying the code ... But I'll keep that in mind for bigger and more important projects

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Your code is a ONE-to-ONE with user.  When you set it, it implies CASCADE delete, and therefore can never be null.

if you change to One-to-Many, and just ensure that you only insert one object for the foreign key, it'll work. Otherwise, change your cascade rule.

I will say, however, that's not a good idea, because if you make it null, what separates it from other records.  Consider a second PK field.

Best of luck.